# Short cut in Xcode to switch between help and IDE

Tags: objective-c, xcode, editor

I'm new to the XCode IDE, Mac and IOS programming. Means that I'll swap a lot between help and editor. However when using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I'll not swap between help and IDE but between other open apps.

Does anyone know a short cut to switch between IDE and help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. <kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> will bring the help in XCode (the shortcut is mentioned if you go to the help section)
2. use 1. in combination with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to scroll through all open projects / windows within XCode.

You can have a look to this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH2-SW1): it refers all XCode shortcuts and gesture.

Answer (score 2):

The default shortcut to open the Organizer is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, which you can edit in the Preferences of Xcode if you want.

There is also a shortcut which will directly bring you to the Documentation tab: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.

Additionally, you can set a shortcut to switch between the windows of the active app in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts. The default is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> but I prefer <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd>) will bring up the documentation window.

Also, you can cycle between windows within an application with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (works in any application). You can use that to switch easily between a project window and other open windows, including the documentation window.

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between applications, not windows.

Note that the keyboard shortcut for a given menu command will be displayed in the menu along with the command (this is true for any application):

[image: Help Menu]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mountain Lion (not sure if it works on earlier versions), you can also use the 4 finger scroll (Mission Control shortcut) if you prefer. With the Organizer (help) open, use 4 fingers and swipe upwards to reveal mission control. On top you'll see virtual desktops. Drag and drop your Organizer/help window onto the second desktop. Now you can flick right or left with 4 fingers on your trackpad to switch between code view and help. I know this sounds complicated but once you get used to it, it becomes second nature. But yeah `Cmd + ~` is good too.